# What is the central charge of the disordered $q$-state Potts model, for large $q$?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, conformal-field-theory, spin-models, critical-phenomena, central-charge

The central charge of a model, is, heuristically related to the number of microscopic degrees of freedom. Is there a simple argument for the asymptotic behavior of the central charge for the disordered $q$-state [Potts model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potts_model) for large $q$?

Further, is there any other set of critical lattice models, that show different critical behaviors corresponding to some parameter and all of which appear in the unitary series of 2d CFTs?

Comment: The phase transition of the Potts model is first-order for $q\geq 5$ (in two dimensions), there is no critical point.

Comment: Ah, yes. I am supposed to know that!
I would still ask the same question, with disorder.

Comment: There is an answer at http://www.physicsoverflow.org/25646/